# CSS class orders shows different results

Tags: html, css

The `bb` class background colour would be red if I move the code before the `intro-block` class css codes , however if I put it after the `intro-block` class css codes the colour is not changing and nothing happens!
Could anyone tell me why this happens?!

```css
.left-column {
  width: 35%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.right-column {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.intro-block {
  background-color: #22AAA1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*max-width: 950px;*/}
}

.bb {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <section class="intro-block">
      <div class="left-column">
        <img class="profile-pic right-column" src="img/11.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="right-column">
        <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
        <p>
          <h4>lorem ipsum</h4>
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="bb">
      <h3>lorem ipsum</h3>
      <div class="left-column">
        <div>
          <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-column">
        <h5>lorem ipsum</h5>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

You have an extra `}` just before `.bb  {}`

**Note:** don't wrap headings (`h1` to `h6`) in `p`

You should indent/tidy your code for better reading and with that you will find this mistakes easily

```css
.left-column {
  width: 35%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.right-column {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.intro-block {
  background-color: #22AAA1;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*max-width: 950px;*/
}


.bb {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <section class="intro-block">
      <div class="left-column">
        <img class="profile-pic right-column" src="img/11.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="right-column">
        <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
        <h4>lorem ipsum</h4>
      </div>
    </section>
  </header>
  <main>
    <section class="bb">
      <h3>lorem ipsum</h3>
      <div class="left-column">
        <div>
          <p>lorem ipsum</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-column">
        <h5>lorem ipsum</h5>
      </div>
      </section>
  </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

> /*max-width: 950px;*/**}**

you have an extra } after the quoted line that messes up with the following rules ...